# how to parse transaction in python

Tags: solana-cli, python

I am trying to query a token (USDC for instance) balance for a wallet like that:

```
response = client.get_token_accounts_by_owner(
    Pubkey.from_string(wallet_address),
opts=TokenAccountOpts(mint=Pubkey.from_string('EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v')), # USDC
            commitment=Confirmed
        )
```

But I don't manage to decode the data then. Any idea how I could do please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the token accounts yourself, but it'll be easier to instead call `get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed`, and that way you'll get them in an easily readable format, ie:

```
response = client.get_token_accounts_by_owner_json_parsed(
    Pubkey.from_string(wallet_address),
opts=TokenAccountOpts(mint=Pubkey.from_string('EPjFWdd5AufqSSqeM2qN1xzybapC8G4wEGGkZwyTDt1v')), # USDC
            commitment=Confirmed
        )
```